# How to setup NSArrayController with Core Data?

Tags: objective-c, macos, core-data, nsarraycontroller

I am trying to programmatically setup an `NSArrayController` to work with Core Data.

I know that my Core Data store has content since I can manually retrieve objects through the managed object context. I hooked up an `NSArrayController` to the same managed object context and then bound the value parameter of a `NSTableColumn` to the `NSArrayController`.

I asked the `NSArrayController` to fetch but it returns an empty array.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong?

Interface

```
@interface MTTableViewController : NSObject <NSTableViewDelegate, NSTableViewDataSource>
{
    NSMutableArray *tableData;
    MTTableCell *tableCell;        

    IBOutlet NSTableColumn *tableColumn;        
    NSArrayController *dataController;
}
```

Implementation

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];

    if (self)
    {
        dataController = [[NSArrayController alloc] init];
        [dataController setManagedObjectContext:[[NSApp delegate] managedObjectContext]];
        [dataController setEntityName:@"Track"];
        [dataController setAutomaticallyPreparesContent:YES];

        [dataController fetch:self];
        NSArray *content = [dataController arrangedObjects];        
        NSLog(@"Count :%i", (int)[content count]); //Outputs 0

        tableCell = [[MTTableCell alloc] initTextCell:@""];
        [tableColumn setDataCell:tableCell];
    }

    return self;
}
```

Comment: are sure your managed object context is initialised in the delegate by the time you assign it to your datacontroller init method.

Comment: I checked the call for the managed object context from the delegate and it is not nil. Any other suggestions?

Comment: try [dataController fetch:self]; after the setup. Shouldn't have to but...

Comment: I tried that but I still get zero objects. The SQLite persistence store is not empty. Ideas?

Comment: try using designated initialiser initWithContent: with nil

Comment: I just tried `initWithContent:` with nil and I am still getting zero.

Comment: I got it to work by sending the array controller a fetch request `[dataController fetchWithRequest:nil merge:NO error:nil]`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5261/discussion-between-warren-burton-and-david)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `fetch:` doesn't wait for data to be loaded, instead it returns instantly.

This makes sense in bindings-enabled environment. You usually have a table view bound to an array controller, which updates whenever controller content changes.

In this case you could observe for changes in `arrangedObjects` of the controller:

```
[self.arrayController addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"arrangedObjects" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

And then:

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  NSLog(@"Data: %@", self.arrayController.arrangedObjects);
}
```

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389460