# ViewModel has 0 items on the first few calls from AppDelegate

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data

This is a part of `updateStatusData()` in my AppDelegate

```
viewModel?.arrayController.arrangedObjects as! [Item]
```

Then I loop through the objects and format them to some string.

On the first call from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` the line above returns an empty list of objects.

`applicationDidFinishLaunching` has the following line right at the beginning `viewModel = ViewModel()` And then all other initialization parts like `updateStatusData()`

When called using timer, it loads the data after a couple of loops.

ViewModel looks something like this

```
class ViewModel {
    let arrayController = ViewArrayController() // this is nsarraycontroller
    let moc = CoreDataManager.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    
    init() {
        arrayController.managedObjectContext = moc
        arrayController.bind(NSBindingName.managedObjectContext, to: moc, withKeyPath: "self", options: nil)
        arrayController.entityName = "Item"
        arrayController.automaticallyPreparesContent = true
        arrayController.avoidsEmptySelection = true
        arrayController.preservesSelection = true
        arrayController.selectsInsertedObjects = true
        arrayController.clearsFilterPredicateOnInsertion = true
        arrayController.usesLazyFetching = false
        arrayController.fetch(nil)
    }

}
```

What should I do to load the data after the first call from `applicationDidFinishLaunching`?
This is a menubar. It displays the icon but as explained above, coredata items get loaded after a few loops. And I need to have the initial data in menubar as the app starts.

Comment: See [fetch](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsobjectcontroller/1524554-fetch) "Beginning with OS X v10.4 the result of this method is deferred until the next iteration of the runloop".

Comment: @Willeke, Is it a good idea to solve this problem buy providing some delay like `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5) { ...`?

Comment: @kirge No, see [How do you populate a NSArrayController with CoreData rows programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13389460).